# What season was it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers, seasonal

A puzzle maker wrote this in his notebook as a holiday puzzle:

> *Th bbie sartd unning.*

What season was it?

Comment: Why was this puzzle downvoted so much?

Comment: See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/why-is-my-question-so-poorly-received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Spring

The words appear to be missing letters. If the sentence should be:

> Th**e** b**a**bie**s** s**t**art**e**d **r**unning

Then the missing letters spell

> easter

Which is in the stated season.

Comment: This was exactly my intended solution!